# Memory usage doesn't decrease upon calling free

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I have a WebSocket Server using C that will run as a background process on Windows. And this process will accept requests that contains large image data (base64 format).

Everytime a request is received, memory is allocated using malloc. And free'd after the request is executed.

But when I check the Task Manager, the memory usage is not decreased. Also, when I send another request, additional memory is allocated.

My question is, why didn't the process released the allocated memory or reused the previously allocated memory?

Comment: What Windows OS version is that?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 4):

The underlying implementation of `free` differs on different platforms, but what you are witnessing is most likely due to *lazy* memory allocation/deallocation. Your OS (or memory management routines) are aware of the memory that you just freed, but since it is likely that your program is going to request more memory again, it doesn't bother making that memory available to other processes until other processes request it. Hence, the task manager shows that your program's memory usage does not decrease, despite calls to free.

If your program frees and then requests more memory, the underlying memory management routines don't have to give you back the same memory that you freed. Combining free blocks is called [coalescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coalescing_(computer_science)), and is an expensive operation, so it will be delayed to the last moment, and not done at all if possible.

To prove this, you can spin up another program, and have it request a large amount of memory - if your original program properly freed the memory, its memory usage will go down as soon as the new program requests memory.

Comment: The decision to hold onto memory may be in the in-task memory management routines, rather than the operating system.

Comment: When I tried to process another request (with malloc), why did the memory usage increased again instead of using the free'd memory?

Comment: @Ronnie: Probably because the freed memory wasn't big enough — that's the most usual reason. That is, you freed 1 MiB but the next request was for 1.2 MiB, and there wasn't already a block that large available, so it allocated a new one.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Ronnie I edited my answer (in the middle) to answer that.

Comment: +1 it's implementation dependent and that OS (which version - would be interesting to know) might choose to keep a pointer to the next available area *unless* the remaining memory from that pointer is not big enough to do that. The coalescing operation being, indeed, expensive. This is a viable solution, while not optimal in terms of memory management.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am sending the same request (same length)

Comment: @Ronnie: OK.  Let's see, which system are you working on?  Oh, Windows.  I don't know enough about Windows to be able to help with the behaviour of its memory allocation systems — either at the o/s level or the C runtime library level.  In principle, it could be returning the same address as was freed. If it doesn't, there are probably good reasons, and they might even be documented somewhere (but I know not where). For example, it might decide to allocate a big chunk and cycle around that big chunk allocating sections of it in turn. There may be other memory allocations causing fragmentation.

Comment: @vasia When I free'd the allocated memory and then allocate the same amount of memory on the next request, does coalescing still happens? I observed from the Task Manager that the memory usage is increased with the same amount everytime I send the same request again and again. For example, the initial memory usage of the process is 2MB, but everytime I send the same request, an additional 3MB is added on the memory usage of the process. No reduction or reuse is done.

Comment: 2MB is a pretty small size for a block of memory for your memory management routines to bother coalescing it right away. Nowadays we're dealing with GBs of RAM after all. So no, if you free the allocated memory and then allocate the same amount of memory on the next request, coalescing is not guaranteed to happen. The behavior that you observe however, will not persist if you free/allocate memory hundreds of times - eventually the memory manager will be forced to coalesce free blocks. An efficient implementation will use heuristics to wait until the most opportune moment to do so. @Ronnie

Comment: @vasia Do you mean that the memory usage of the process will keep increasing on every request? And the process will not reuse the free'd memory unless there is a need?

Comment: @Ronnie it's not so simple. The _reported_ memory usage of the process is not guaranteed to increase with every request. It depends on many factors, namely how much memory your process is using, how much memory other processes are using, and what the fragmentation of free/used memory looks like. 

One thing that **can** be said with certainty is that the process **will** reuse (properly) freed memory if there is no other memory to use. However, it is very likely that it will reuse that memory much sooner than that. 

Also, task manager does not give you exact memory usage.

Comment: @vasia Can you define properly? And what are improper implementations of free?

Comment: @Ronnie I'm not talking about improper _implementations_ of free, I'm talking about improper **use** of it. When I say properly freed memory, I just mean that **1)** You allocate memory with malloc, and receive a pointer to that memory. **2)** When you are done you call free on that memory, only once.

Comment: @vasia If I am doing that, does that mean I should not worry on the memory usage of the process displayed on the Task Manager?

Comment: @Ronnie if you are worried about running out of memory, you can make sure that you don't have a memory leak. Try calling malloc and then free in your program, as you have it, about 1000-10000 times. If you don't have any bugs you shouldn't run out of memory, because your process will reuse the freed memory.  

I am not sure what your question is saying - "If I am doing that, does that mean I should not worry on the memory usage of the process displayed on the Task Manager?"